# Spring batch JdbcBatchItemWriter insert is very slow with MYSQL

Tags: spring-batch

I'm using a chunk step with a reader and writer. I am reading data from Hive with 50000 chunk size and insert into mysql with same 50000 commit.

```
@Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Identity> writer(DataSource mysqlDataSource) {
        return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<Identity>()
                .itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>())
                .sql(insertSql)
                .dataSource(mysqlDataSource)
                .build();
    }
```

When i have started dataload and insert into Mysql  its commiting very slow and 100000 records are takiing more than a hr to load while same loader with Gemfire loading 5 million recordsin 30 min.

seems like it insert one by one insted of batch as laoding 1500 then 4000 then ....etc ,does anyone faced same issue ?

Comment: please share the sql statement `insertSql` that you are using

Comment: I have only 8 column and sql is simple however its inserting records one by one                                                        INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...) VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);

Comment: `seems like it insert one by one insted of batch`: The `JdbcBatchItemWriter` does not inset items one by one, it inserts them with a JDBC batch update in a single transaction: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/c4010fbffa6b71cbcfe79d523023251ce73666a4/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcBatchItemWriter.java#L189-L193. Similar to the answer by @Binu, try to write a custom `SqlParameterSourceProvider` that does not use reflection and see if it improves performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider`, this will include lot of reflection to set variables in prepared statement.This will increase time.

If speed is the your high priority try implementing your own `ItemWriter` as given below and use prepared statement batch to execute update.

```
@Component
public class CustomWriter implements ItemWriter<Identity> {
    //your sql statement here
    private static final String SQL = "INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...) VALUES (?,?,?,?);";

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends Identity> list) throws Exception {

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dataSource.getConnection().prepareStatement(SQL);
        for (Identity identity : list) {
            // Set the variables
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, identity.getMxx());
            preparedStatement.setString(2, identity.getMyx());
            preparedStatement.setString(3, identity.getMxt());
            preparedStatement.setInt(4, identity.getMxt());
            // Add it to the batch
            preparedStatement.addBatch();

        }
        int[] count = preparedStatement.executeBatch();
    }

}
```

**Note:** This is a rough code. So Exception handling and resource handling is not done properly. You can work on the same. I think this will improve your writing speed very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding ";useBulkCopyForBatchInsert=true" to your connection url.

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl + ";useBulkCopyForBatchInsert=true")
```

Source : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/use-bulk-copy-api-batch-insert-operation?view=sql-server-ver15