# JdbcBatchItemWriter multi thread

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-batch

Is there any way to multi thread a JdbcBatchItemWriter.
I have a batch which should insert many lines( + 1M lines).

```
@Bean
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<MyDTO> InitWriter() {
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<MyDTO> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<MyDTO>();
    writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<MyDTO>());
    writer.setSql("INSERT INTO ....");
    writer.setDataSource(cloudDataSource);

    return writer;
}
```

this took me forever.

Comment: this will be helpful https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-step-partitioning/

Comment: No need to execute JdbcBatchItemWriter in parallel, let Spring Batch take care of it through partitioning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring batch JdbcBatchItemWriter insert is very slow with MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60140822/spring-batch-jdbcbatchitemwriter-insert-is-very-slow-with-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JdbcBatchItemWriter` is thread-safe, so you can use it in multiple concurrent transactions. Here is an excerpt from its [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcBatchItemWriter.html):

> The writer is thread-safe after its properties are set (normal singleton behavior), so it can be used to write in multiple concurrent transactions.

So in your case, you can try to use a [Multi-threaded Step](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/scalability.html#multithreadedStep) and see if it improves your job's performance.